# Как растянуть блок на всю высоту?

Tags: flutter, dart

Перепробовал все известные мне варианты, ничего не получается. Жаль нельзя выражать высоту и длину в процентах, как в css(. Поэтому возникло три вопроса.
1. Как можно растянуть зеленую полоску (как на картинке) во всю высоту родительского блока?
Высота родительского блока может меняться в зависимости от контента, то есть она не фиксирована.
2. Как сделать так, чтобы этот блок (зеленая линия) не накладывался поверх родительского блока, чтобы углы так же обрезались?
3. Как реализовать пятерку над надписью "Астрономия"?
Код того, что я пытаюсь реализовать:

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13), 
      color: Colors.white),
    child: Row(children: [
      Expanded(flex: 11, child: 
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(widget.subject.title, style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                fontSize: 21
              )), // название предмета
              content() // Тут находится текст домашнего задания
            ]
          )
        )
      ),
      Container(
        width: 7, 
        height: 10, // Как задать высоту этого блока, как у родителя, чтобы он перекрывал его, а так же обрезался по углам
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ])
  )
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Код (который можно воспроизвести) приложите пожалуйста!

Comment: Готово, приложил код

Comment: И если будут какие-то замечания по форматированию кода, то буду рад слышать

Answer (score 1):

Для зеленой полоски можно использовать градиент с совмещенными контрольными точками (в [приведенном примере](https://dartpad.dev/a7b45d78a1824dfe8af567f2a64424f2) это позиция 94%) и задать его фоном контейнера с текстом. В том-же декораторе задаем радиус закруглений.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 32, 16),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.grey[200],
                Colors.grey[200],
                Colors.green,
                Colors.green
              ],
              stops: [0.0, 0.94, 0.94, 1.0],
            )),
        child: Text("Hello, World!",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4));
  }
}
```

Пятерку в суперскрипте можно реализовать юникодом `"Астрономия\u2075"` или через `RichText`.

Comment: Как можно реализовать через RichText?

Comment: Всё, спасибо, реализовал через юникод

Comment: Интересный способ, надо будет запомнить)

Answer (score 0):

С пятеркой ещё нужно поиграться:

```
Container(
  //margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13), color: Colors.white),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 11,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "5",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Название",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 21),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ), // название предмета
                  Text(
                    "Тут находится текст домашнего задания Тут находится текст домашнего задания Тут находится текст домашнего задания Тут находится текст домашнего задания",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
                    ), // Тут находится текст домашнего задания
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 7,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                .size
                .height, // Как задать высоту этого блока, как у родителя, чтобы он перекрывал его, а так же обрезался по углам
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Теперь получилось, что блок растянут на высоту экрана

Comment: Может вместо контейнера какой-то другой блок июзать?

Comment: @ДаниилЧашков SizedBox если только))

Comment: Использовал sizedbox.expand(тут контейнер), блок вообще исчез

Comment: @ДаниилЧашков без expand, задайте размер сами.

Comment: Так суть в том, что он автоматический должен растягиваться на высоту родителя

Comment: Иначе весь план рушится

Comment: @ДаниилЧашков ишите что вам нужно https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout

Answer (score 0):

В общем, всё оказалось на порядок проще.
Вовсе не надо растягивать на всю высоту.
Достаточно взять контейнер, перекрасить его в нужный цвет, добавить внутренний отступ справа, в качестве ребёнка взять еще контейнер. В итоге получилось то, что хотел.
Пятерку реализовал с помощью RichText + unicode

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(13), 
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(13)), 
        color: Colors.white),
      child: 
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: "${widget.subject.title}", // название предмета
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, 
                    fontSize: 21
                  ),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: '${widget.homework.grade == null ? "" : " "+numbers[widget.homework.grade]}',// оценка (пятерка)
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        color: Colors.grey)
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ),// название предмета
              content(),// Тут находится текст домашнего задания
            ],
          ),
        ),
    ),
  ),
```